# Check if an element contains a specific child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have many `div`s which sometimes contain links. I want check whether or not they have a link. This is my attempt:

```
var container = $(this).closest('.content').find('.text');

    //Check if text contains a tags
    if(container+':has(a)'){
        alert('contain link'); 
    }
    else{
        alert('no link found');  //Alert "contain link" even if no link is found.
    }
```

By doing `container.html()` I can see the exact content of `container` including anchor tags, but my code above will always say that it cannot find the anchor tag.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *`container+':has(a)'`* What do you think the result of applying the `+` operator on operands that are an object and a string will be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change to this:

```
if(container.find("a").length){ ...
```

`container` is a jquery object and `.find()` is a function of that object that finds elements within it. A length greater than 0 will mean it finds an anchor tag and it will evaluate to true.

**Edit:**

Also, to explain why your example isn't working. When you do `container+':has(a)'`, you are doing a string concatenation which runs `toString()` on your object (converting it to "[object Object]"). So you end up with the string "[object Object]:has(a)" which will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Good point. One should not concatenate a string with an object. It just wont work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `length` property of a selector to determine if any elements were found. Try this:

```
var $container = $(this).closest('.content').find('.text');

if ($('a', $container).length) {
    alert('Contains links'); 
}
else {
    alert('No links found');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(container+':has(a)'){
```

To

```
if(container.has('a').size()){
```

container is an jquery object, not a selector string

Comment: This will not work - has() will actually return a jquery object subset of container which will evaluate to true whether or not it contains elements - http://jsfiddle.net/7V3Hy/3/

Comment: just realized that 'has' method returns jquery object, ty a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yours will work if you change it to

```
 if($(container+":has(a)").length > 0){
```

[In docs](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

> The supplied selector is tested against the descendants of the matching elements

Comment: This won't work either, when you try to concatenate container with a string, it will convert container from a jquery object into a string ("[object Object]") then you will get a syntax error when you try to create a jquery from that. This would work: `container.has("a").length`, but there's no reason to check if `>0` as 0 will evaluate to false and any other outcome would evaluate to true.